# jQuery Date Picker Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a situation where the jQuery date picker not working in one of the IE (it work perfectly fine in other IE with same version).

When user select on the date picker, the calendar come out as a drop down, but the **date is not able to select and also unable to select other months**.

The code as below:

```
<script src="../../../JS/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../JS/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ defaultDate: +0, showOn: 'button', buttonImage: 'calendar.gif', buttonImageOnly: true, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="115px" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
```

[image]

could this due to the setting of IE? please help.

thank you in advanced.

UPDATE

- try to switch between document mode and browser mode in IE, but not able to solve the problem
- try script debugging in IE developer tool, no error found.

Comment: Check error console and there might be something with visibility: hidden above the area with the datepicker

Comment: I've got $10 on Compatibility Mode. Anyone else?

Comment: I've tried start debugging in IE developer tool, there was no script error

Comment: Hi All, the issue above already solved by change the configuration in IE Internet Options

Comment: @sams5817  Please be more specific!  What option did you change?  This will help others in a similar situation ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your selector is not rendered correctly

try this: separating rendering of js variable away from selector:

```
<%=string.Format("var datepicker=#{0}",txtDate.ClientID) %>

 $("#"+datepicker).datepicker({ defaultDate: +0, showOn: 'button', buttonImage: 'calendar.gif', buttonImageOnly: true, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```